# Surjective homomorphism of groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S,*$ and $T,\#$ be binary structures. A homomorphism from $S,*$ to $T,\#$ is a map $h:S\to T$ such that $h(x*y)=h(x)\# h(y)$. Prove that if $h:S,* \to T,\#$ is a surjective homomorphism and $S,*$ is a group then $T,\#$ is a group.

I was stuck on this problem. I have no idea how to prove this problem. Can someone help me please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. You need to show that $\#$ is associative, that is, for $t_1,t_2,t_3\in T$, $t_1\mathbin{\#}(t_2\mathbin{\#}t_3)=(t_1\mathbin{\#}t_2)\mathbin{\#}t_3$.

**Hint:** Let $h(s_1)=t_1$, $h(s_2)=t_2$ and $h(s_3)=t_3$. By hypothesis, $s_1*(s_2*s_3)=(s_1*s_2)*s_3$. Apply $h$ to both sides.

B. You need to find $e_T\in T$ such that $t\mathbin{\#}e_T=t=e_T\mathbin{\#}t$, for all $t\in T$.

**Hint:** There is $e_S\in S$ such that, for all $s\in S$, $s*e_S=s=e_S*s$; consider $e_T=h(e_S)$.

C. For $t\in T$, you need to find $t'\in T$ such that $t\mathbin{\#}t'=e_T=t'\mathbin{\#}t$.

**Hint:** let $s\in S$ such that $h(s)=t$ and consider $s'\in S$ such that $s*s'=e_S=s'*s$.